# Laravel - passing parameters from web.php routes to controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a parameter to my UserController but i can't seem to find a method to do this. All other topics give examples where the parameter is already defined in the url but that is not what i want.

```
$my_var = "some data";
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\UserController@login');
```

I need $my_var in my UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function login()
    {
        // Retreive $my_var somehow
        return view("login");
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language

Comment: This is not how you work with a framework like that. What are you trying to do? What does $my_var contain and where does that content come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases using hardcoded parameters might be reasonable way to go, and one such could be case where you need to get different kinds of entities from single controller.

For an example you could have restful "users/" -route, which fetches all users from UserModel. Next you wish to separate "normal" users and admin-users by having "admin-users/" -route. Now one way to go is to represent both routes to web.php, and make them point to same controller:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('admin-users', 'UserController');
```

One way to solve this separation is by not passing an argument, but by detecting which route was called:

```
$sqlFilters['user_is_admin'] = $request->is('admin-users') || $request->is('admin-users/*');
```

This checks whether controller was accessed via "admin-users". Asterisk is wildcard for any route under "admin-users" path.

This method has been existing at least since Laravel 6.0, probably even before that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#inspecting-the-request-path

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. That's not how you work with an MVC framework and it's better not to define a variable or constant in `web.php` which is for your routes and middlewares only. By the way, if you need to do it this way, you have two ways:

1) Use a trait:

**web.php**:

```
trait TestTrait {
    public static $my_var = 'some data';
}

Route::get(/login', 'Auth\UserController@login');
```

**UserConroller.php**:

```
use TestTrait;

class UserController extends Controller
{
use TestTrait;

public function login()
{
    // You can retrieve it as a variable: $my_var
    echo TestTrait::$my_var;
}
}
```

2) Use a constant instead of a variable:

**web.php**:

```
define('MY_VAR', 'some data');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\UserController@login');
```

**UserConroller.php**:

```
public function login()
{
    // You can retrieve it as a constant: MY_VAR
    echo MY_VAR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is hardcoded, why not state it as a constant?
If no other logic is needed, the variable can be passed through the routes file.

```
$my_var = "some data";
Route::get('/login', function(){
Return view('login', compact('my_var')):
});
```